# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv1d" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 172)

Tags: python, keras

```
print("x: ", x_train.shape)
print("x: ", x_test.shape)
print("y: ", y_train.shape)
print("y: ", y_test.shape)
```

........................output..............................
x:  (172, 1177)
x:  (30, 1177)
y:  (172,)
y:  (30,)

......................................

```
from keras.models import Sequential
import keras
from keras.layers import Conv1D
model = Sequential()
y_train1 = y_train
y_test1 = y_test
# Conv1:
model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters = 32, kernel_size=1,strides = 1, activation='relu', input_shape=(128,1)))
# Conv2:
model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters = 32, kernel_size=1,strides = 1, activation='relu'))
# Pool1:
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=(3), strides = 1))
# BN1:
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
# Conv3:
model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters = 64, kernel_size=1,strides = 1, activation='relu'))
# Conv4:
model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters = 64, kernel_size=1,strides = 1, activation='relu'))
# Pool2:
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=(3), strides = 1))
# BN2:
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters = 128, kernel_size=1,strides = 1, activation='relu'))
# Conv6:
model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters = 128, kernel_size=1,strides = 1, activation='relu'))
# Pool3:
model.add(keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D())
# BN4:
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

import tensorflow as tf
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
# Dense1:
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation='relu',use_bias=True))
# Dense2:
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu',use_bias=True))
# BN3:
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
# Dense3:
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=16, activation='softmax',use_bias=True))
model.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = tf.losses.binary_crossentropy, metrics = ['accuracy'])
#
# epochs = 50
# batch_size = 64
# model.save("my_model.h5")
model.summary()
```

.........................................output............................................

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv1d (Conv1D)             (None, 128, 32)           64        
                                                                 
 conv1d_1 (Conv1D)           (None, 128, 32)           1056      
                                                                 
 max_pooling1d (MaxPooling1D  (None, 126, 32)          0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 batch_normalization (BatchN  (None, 126, 32)          128       
 ormalization)                                                   
                                                                 
 conv1d_2 (Conv1D)           (None, 126, 64)           2112      
                                                                 
 conv1d_3 (Conv1D)           (None, 126, 64)           4160      
                                                                 
 max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling  (None, 124, 64)          0         
 1D)                                                             
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_1 (Batc  (None, 124, 64)          256       
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 conv1d_4 (Conv1D)           (None, 124, 128)          8320      
                                                                 
 conv1d_5 (Conv1D)           (None, 124, 128)          16512     
                                                                 
 global_max_pooling1d (Globa  (None, 128)              0         
 lMaxPooling1D)                                                  
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_2 (Batc  (None, 128)              512       
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 128)               0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 256)               33024     
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 128)               32896     
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_3 (Batc  (None, 128)              512       
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 16)                2064      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 101,616
Trainable params: 100,912
Non-trainable params: 704
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/43
```

```
model_history = model.fit(x_train,y_train1, batch_size=32, epochs=43, verbose=1)
```

**....................................................Error...........................................**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rulzem\PycharmProjects\fyp preprocessing\main.py", line 453, in <module>
    model_history = model.fit(x_train,y_train1, batch_size=32, epochs=43, verbose=1)
  File "E:\BS-IT\semester no.7\Final Year Project- Capstone I\preprocessing\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\rulzem\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_fileqs1j0crv.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
ValueError: in user code:

    File "E:\BS-IT\semester no.7\Final Year Project- Capstone I\preprocessing\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1249, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "E:\BS-IT\semester no.7\Final Year Project- Capstone I\preprocessing\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1233, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "E:\BS-IT\semester no.7\Final Year Project- Capstone I\preprocessing\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1222, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "E:\BS-IT\semester no.7\Final Year Project- Capstone I\preprocessing\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1023, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "E:\BS-IT\semester no.7\Final Year Project- Capstone I\preprocessing\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "E:\BS-IT\semester no.7\Final Year Project- Capstone I\preprocessing\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_spec.py", line 295, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    **ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 128, 1), found shape=(None, 1177)**
```

I am applying CNN model but at the time of model fitting i am getting errror, i tried many solutions but no one work

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250639/discussion-on-question-by-fyp-group-valueerror-input-0-of-layer-conv1d-is-inc).